# Programmatically create confluence content from jira and fisheye

Tags: python, automation, jira, confluence, asciidoctor

I'm curious, how a good automated workflow could look like for the process of automating issues/touched file lists into a confluence page. I describe my current idea here:

- Get all issues matching my request from JIRA using REST (DONE)
- Get all touched files related to the matching Issues using Fisheye REST
- Create a .adoc file with the content
- Render it using asciidoctor-confluence to a confluence page

I'm implementing the this in python (using requests etc.) and I wonder how I could provide proper .adoc for the ruby-based asciidoctor. I'm planning to use asciidoctor for the reason it has an option to render directly to confluence using `asciidocter-confluence`.

So, is there anybody who can kindly elaborate on my idea?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar - getting info from Jira and updating confluence info.

I did it in a bash script that ran on Jenkins. The script:

- Got Jira info using the Jira REST API
- Parsed the JSON from Jira using jq (wonderful tool)
- Created/updated the confluence page using the Confluence REST API

I have not used python but the combination of bash/REST/jq was very simple. Running the script from Jenkins allowed me to run this periodically, so confluence is updated automatically every 2 weeks with the new info from Jira.

Comment: I've got some web-resource fetching, parsing and calculation to do which I'd prefer to solve with a more structured approach, that is python. The approach I'm describing collects issues fixed between minor releases and hotfixes and will be run several times a day during snapshot build. Anyway, I'm currently thinking about, if the beautification using asciidoctor is really necessary. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can create macros and so on with the confluence rest api. My script creates graphs on confluence (as chart macros) with the jira info. How frequently the script runs can be configured from Jenkins, which uses a cron like format. In the end its best to use the tools you have accessible, and are most familiar with. Good luck.